# comparison between the items of one list with the items of another list both of which reside in an outer list

Tags: python

[working with a big list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932507/working-with-a-big-list/6933284#6933284) This is my earlier post about this program which generates the following list. The program I am writing deals with a big linked list. This list is called phonemeList. The list is like the following:

```
[[('dh', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.35], [-1, -1]]), 

  ('ih', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.3, 1.0], [-1, -1], [0.05, 0.15], [-1,-1]]),  

  ("'", None),  

  ('k', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.8], [-1, -1]]), 

  ('aa', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 1.0], [-1, -1]]), 

  ('r', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.6], [-1, -1]]), 

  ("'", None),  

  ('p', [[-1, -1], [0.2, 1.0], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.2], [-1, -1]]), 

  ('ih', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.3, 1.0], [-1, -1], [0.05, 0.15], [-1, -1]]), 

  ("'", None), 

  ('k', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.8], [-1, -1]]), 

  ('iy', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.3, 1.0], [-1, -1], [0.1, 0.15], [-1, -1]]),

  ('ng', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.3, 1.0], [-1, -1], [0.09, 0.3], [-1, -1]]),

  ("'", None), 

  ('er', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.5], [-1, -1]]), 

  ("'", None), 

  ('sh', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.3, 1.0], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]]), 

  ('eh', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.1, 0.5], [-1, -1], [0.4, 0.7], [-1, -1]]), 

  ('m', [[-1, -1], [0.2, 1.0], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.2], [-1, -1]]), 

  ("'", None), 

  ('p', [[-1, -1], [0.2, 1.0], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.2], [-1, -1]]),

  ('uw', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.5, 1.0]]), 

  ('dx', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.35], [-1, -1]]), 

  ("'", None), 

  ('aa', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 1.0], [-1, -1]]), 

  ("'", None), 

  ('er', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.5], [-1, -1]]), 

  ("'", None), ('aa', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 1.0], [-1,-1]]), 

  ("'", None), 

  ('r', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.6], [-1, -1]]), 

  ('iy', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.3, 1.0], [-1, -1], [0.1, 0.15], [-1, -1]]),

  ("'", None), 

  ('ih', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.3, 1.0], [-1, -1], [0.05, 0.15], [-1, -1]]),

  ('n', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.3, 1.0], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]]), 

  ('t', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.4], [-1, -1]]), 

  ('l', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.6], [-1, -1]]), 

  ("'", None), ('r', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15,0.6], [-1, -1]]), 

  ('ah', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 1.0], [-1, -1]]), 

  ('k', [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1], [0.15, 0.8], [-1, -1]])]]
```

Could you kindly have a look at the link so that you have an idea about the program. Thank you. [0.15,0.6] is not a list but a range. Here it is expressed as a list which may be wrong. This means the value can vary from 0.15 to 0.6. Where as [-1,-1] is a no range thing which is not in use and can be replaced by a range of positive numbers while comparing. Now I need to compare the items of 'dh' with the items of 'ih' . The first item of 'dh' will be compared to first item of 'ih' then 2nd item to 2nd and so on. Then the items of 'dh' will be compared to items of 'k' ignoring "'". 'dh' will be compared to all following the rules. Then 'ih' comes into picture and the same thing is repeated. While doing this ("'", None), should be ignored. The ranges get changed during comparison and [-1,-1] will be replaced. The ("'", None) is like a boundary. After comparison of all items with one another, the next step would be to compare within these boundaries. Being a beginner this is really a complex thing for me. But this is also my main project so please help me with this. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the comparison based upon?

Comment: This is such a horrible code paste

Comment: The comparison is like, say the first phoneme 'dh' is being compared with the next one which is 'ih'. Comparison will be between their items like the first item of dh ie [-1,-1] will be compared to the first item of ih which is also [-1,-1]. Then their second items and third and so on. There are some rules to follow while comparing. One of the rules is, [-1,-1] is like a free slot which can be replaced by the range of +ve numbers when it encounters one. I should write all the rules of comparison as well.

Comment: I could start with this rule and perhaps do the other rules myself but I need a starting point from where I could proceed. Thank you

Comment: Description of your problem is too vague. Also you should state clearly what you want to get as a result. It is impossible to help you without understanding the final target. As for start point, I can suggest you make a closer look into that terrible data structure. Obviously it should be converted into something that fits better to your purposes. For example that delimiters become unnecessary if you add new hierarchy level to your main list. So you could split your task into simpler subtasks - get short lists and compare items inside of that lists in turn.

Comment: This is a kind of continuation of a question I posted earlier. Since it has so much data I had to post another question. Yes this is a horrible list to work with and difficult to explain the comparison when the list is this big. Also the list is supposed to have only two digits after the decimal but when it was generated like this. I would edit my question and add more information in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, sounds like you need a class, not a nested list.

```
class Phoneme():
    def __init__(self,named,variables,for,every,paired,value,in,the,crazy,list,you,posted):
        self.named = named
        self.variables = variables
        ##etc
        ##This way, we can see what you're comparing. The comparisons also become much easier.
```

Now your compares can literally just be something like:

```
if phoneme1.fricative == phoneme2.fricative:
    do_something_awesome()
```

Ah, if classes are confusing, I'd suggest you [check](http://pytut.infogami.com/node11-baseline.html) [out](http://www.sthurlow.com/python/lesson08/) [these](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/OOP.shtml) [links.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) Those 4 tutorials are fairly decent descriptions of classes. The last one is the official tutorial, start with that one. [Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.net/) is another excellent example, but it's geared towards those who already know another programming language, so if Python is your first, it might be a bit daunting.

Comment: Thank you. I had thought about classes but though they solve the problems but I have always been confused about classes. You are absolutely right I need a class. I would work on it and see where I get.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide links to good python tutorials with clear examples of classes. I forgot to include www.showmedo.com, which has a ton of video tutorials for Python.

Comment: Thank you. Will look into them.